# CSS select element only when it contains n elements

Tags: html, css

I have an html structure similar to this:

```html
<div class="node">
  <div class="children">
    <div class="nodes"></div>
    <hr/>
  </div>
  <div class="name">This is the node's name!</div>
</div>
```

I want the `div.node > div.name` to have a green background but only when the `div.node > div.children > div.nodes` is empty.

I wanted to count all elements in the `div.node > div.children` and if there are only two (`div.node > div.children > div.nodes` and `div.node > div.children > hr`), I want the following `div.node > div.name` to have a green background.

The selector I imagined would be this: `div.node > div.children:contains(2) + div.name` buit obviously this doesn't work.

Any ideas to solve this issue?

**Edit:**

I was able to remove the `div.node > div.children`. Now my html structure looks like this:

```html
<div class="node">
  <div class="nodes"></div>
  <hr/>
  <div class="name">This is the node's name!</div>
</div>
```

With this structure I can use the `:empty` selector:

```css
div.node > div.nodes:empty + hr + div.name {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: You can't do that with CSS alone. You can either do it in the browser with Javascript or even better would be to just set an appropriate class on the server side when the HTML is getting rendered.

Comment: I didn't want to set a class at the server side or use JS because this structure can be edited. Making this pure CSS will save me a lot of time later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing in CSS (sadly) but you have JS.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.node').forEach(node => {
  const childrensCount = node.querySelectorAll('.children').length;

  if(childrensCount === 2) {
    node.querySelector('.name').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="node">
  <div class="children">
    <div class="nodes"></div>
    <hr/>
  </div>
  <div class="name">This is the node's name!</div>
</div>
<div class="node">
  <div class="children">
    <div class="nodes"></div>
    <hr/>
  </div>
  <div class="children">
    <div class="nodes"></div>
    <hr/>
  </div>
  <div class="name">This is the node's name!</div>
</div>
<div class="node">
  <div class="children">
    <div class="nodes"></div>
    <hr/>
  </div>
  <div class="children">
    <div class="nodes"></div>
    <hr/>
  </div>
  <div class="children">
    <div class="nodes"></div>
    <hr/>
  </div>
  <div class="name">This is the node's name!</div>
</div>
```

**PS**
as cloned mentioned in his comment event better approach will be to set a class like `.bg-green` to name when element is rendered before sending it to user browser